# Changing margins on a Div doesn't take affect?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change my footers margin so that it expands to the width of the webpage, instead it still seems to be affect by the 50px of left/right margin I added to my `#content` section. What property am I missing here so I can remove the affect of the content's margins on my footer section?

### Html

```
<div id="wrapper" />
      <div id="header" />
      <div id="mast"><img src="http://i1256.photobucket.com/albums/ii488/terafanb/guildwars2/26.png" height="99" width="774=" /></div>
      <div id="below-mast" />
      <div id="left" class="column"><img src="http://i157.photobucket.com/albums/t60/Dragon_Aleph/fantasy_warrior_23022-800x600.jpg" height="297" width="226" border="0" alt="Crusader Army" /></div>
      <div id="center" class="column"><img src="http://i157.photobucket.com/albums/t60/Dragon_Aleph/fantasy_warrior_23022-800x600.jpg" height="297" width="400" border="0" alt="Crusader Army" /></div>
      <div id="right" class="column"><img src="http://i157.photobucket.com/albums/t60/Dragon_Aleph/fantasy_warrior_23022-800x600.jpg" height="297" width="139" border="0" alt="Crusader Army" /></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="content" />
      <p>
      <div class="Heading">Forward Exchange *</div>
      $500.00 - collected upon the closing of the Relinquished Property.
      $500.00 - collected upon closing of each Replacement Property purchased.
      * Special credits may apply - Call Us.<br /></br>
      <div id="we-pay">
        <br />
        <div class="Heading">We pay interest</div>
        </br>
        We provide full disclosure of the fees involved in the transaction in the Exchange Agreement. Our customers are entitled to receive earned interest based on the First National Bank of Durango Investment Money Market rate, from the time when the Relinquished Property funds are initially deposited. Interest does not accrue on those funds withdrawn during the first 30 calendar days after the funds are deposited in the Exchange Trust Account. Also, interest does not accrue if customer elects to have exchange funds held at First National Bank of Durango in an Unlimited FDIC insurance non-interest bearing account (available through December 31, 2012)
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="Heading">
        Safe-Harbor Reverse Exchange <br />
        <h2>We charge the following fees:</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="prices">$2,500.00 – Title holding fee<br /> 
        $500.00 – LLC fee<br />
        $200.00 – Monthly Rent<br />
        Plus – Forward Exchange fees<br />
        <br />
      </div>
      <div id="note">
        <p>Note: If any improvements need to be made to the parked property,
          being held by the EAT ( Exchange Accommodator Titleholder )
          there will be an additional fee of 1% of the final sales price to Taxpayer.
        </p>
        <div>
          <br /></br>
          <div id="disclaimer">Fees are subject to change without prior notice</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          <strong>l</strong> <a href="whatIs1031.html">What is a 1031 Exchange?</a> <strong>l</strong> <a href="exchangeRequ.html">
          1031 Exchange Requirements</a> <strong>l</strong> <a href="typesOfExchange.html">Types of Exchanges</a> <br />
          <div id="Second-Half">              
            <a href="howToStart.html">How to get Started</a> <strong>l</strong> 
            <a href="whyCLX.html">Why CLX?</a><strong>l</strong> <a href="resources.html">Resources</a> <strong>l</strong> <a href="fAQs.html">FAQs</a> <strong>l</strong> <a href="fees.html">Fees</a> 
            <a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

### CSS

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#wrapper {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;width:774px;}
#below-mast { width:774px; overflow:hidden; }
#left {height:297px; width:29%; margin:4px;margin-left:0px;}
#center{height:297px; width:51%; margin:4px;}
#right {height:297px; width:17%; margin:4px;}
#left,  #center, #right { float:left;margin-bottom:50px;}
#content{overflow:;margin:0px;margin-top:100px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin-right:50px;margin-left:50px;}
.Heading{font-size:19px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; text-decoration:underline}
.Heading>h2{font-size:13px;text-decoration:none}
#we-pay{font-size:13px}
#we-pay>.Heading{font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;}
#prices{text-align:center; font-size:20px;}
#note{text-align:center;}
#disclaimer{font-size:13px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;font-style:italic; }
#footer{margin-right:-50px;margin-left:-50px;}
#footer,a:link{font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#300000; margin-top:50px;}
#Second-Half{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;width:450px;}
```

Here is a link to my code on Code Pen for your convience
http://codepen.io/Austin-Davis/pen/rLeEi

Answer (score 1):

Your bug can be fixed with the following piece of code:

```
#footer { margin: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; }
```

Please checkout: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/uBikf

PS: I gave the footer a gray background for testing purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the input but the footer is still affected by the content's margin.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I was just missing a closing `</div>` on my #note section making the footer part of the content section, thus making any margin changes to the footer via css useless.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to move the footer outside of the #wrapper div.
Also please check your HTML.. it´s broken in so many places that fixing the css problem might be impossible ;)

eg. you have alot of selfclosing tags "" (not valid)
Also you are missing closing body tag, none exsisting tags "" etc etc..